# How can I toggle up/down votes on ratings?

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

I'm using the Solspace Rating module and I'd like to be able to allow the user to toggle their vote on ratings.

If a user votes up but later wants to "unvote" or change their vote how can I accomplish this?  It seems that I can allow duplicate votes, but this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete a rating using the `{exp:rating:delete}` tag: http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/delete/

After deleting the rating, the user can try and rate again. That would be the "unvote".

Comment: rating:delete works for the entry rating, but is there a way to delete the rating_vote?

Comment: You could downvote a rating vote. From the [documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/insert_rating_vote/#examples): _... you’ll need to create "**up/down**" voting links in your Rating:Entries loop, like this (URI vote options are **up/yes** and **down/no**). See Rating:Rating_Vote_Stats documentation for more information._

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm trying to only allow only one option for the vote.  If a user votes up on his first vote, I want to limit his second vote to only the down option and vice versa.  This is to prevent users from submitting multiple up votes and spamming the tally. I'm trying to do this with conditionals and the previous_vote variable, but it seems that previous_vote is only showing the FIRST vote not the previous vote.  I've checked the database and the second vote is being recorded but not reflected in the previous_vote variable.  Any ideas?